# Input link in1:v0 parameters do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (ffmpeg SAR error)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resize

I'm getting an SAR error when using complex filters in ffmpeg and I can't quite make sense of it. The input command is as follow (spread over multiple lines for clarity):

```
ffmpeg \
-i '698cc30d2dc966eaf4dc4f6f3571df8d.mp4' \
-i '76a2ffdd0d7e82d31731c6e2c0c6f4c9.mp4' \
-filter_complex "\
    [0:v] setsar=sar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1080x1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [0v]; \
    [1:v] setsar=sar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1080x1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [1v]; \
    [0v][0:a][1v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" \
-max_muxing_queue_size 500 \
-strict -2 \
out.mp4
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> [Parsed_concat_8 @ 0x7fe35a70b100] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1080x1920, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1080x1920, SAR 1216:1215)
>
> [Parsed_concat_8 @ 0x7fe35a70b100] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_8
>
> Error reinitializing filters!
>
> Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
>
> Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0

The complex filters basically scale the videos to the required dimensions (1080x1920) and add black borders below and above, or on the side to make it fit within the rectangle. It worked with some videos but not in this case for some reason and I can't make sense of the error message.

Any idea what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: @Gyan, is it really the exact same question? I see the answer in that other question is to add setsar=1 but I already have this but still getting the same error message?

Comment: Ok I got it working by adding this parameter at the end, as in the linked question. Thanks.